# How can I create a column with incremented values from a column with cumulated values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, window-functions

Table1 contains a column with cumulated values (all positive integers):

```
id ValuesCum
1  5
2  8
3  20
```

I would like to write a statement that returns an extra column with the incremented values for each row. The output should read something like:

```
id ValuesCum ValuesInc
1  5         (5)
2  8         3
3  20        12
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window function `lag()` for this:

```
select
    t.*,
    ValuesCum - lag(ValuesCum, 1, 0) over(order by id) ValuesInc
from mytable t
```

In earlier versions, an alternative is a correlated subquery:

```
select
    t.*,
    ValuesCum - (
        select coalesce(max(t1.ValuesCum), 0)
        from mytable t1
        where t1.id < t.id
    ) ValuesInc

from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery to get the value of `ValuesCum` of the previous `id`:

```
select t.*,
  t.ValuesCum - 
  coalesce((select ValuesCum from tablename where id < t.id order by id desc limit 1), 0) ValuesInc
from tablename t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xdBneX31fYkAm1QkoNmdgj/0).
Results:

```
| id  | ValuesCum | ValuesInc |
| --- | --------- | --------- |
| 1   | 5         | 5         |
| 2   | 8         | 3         |
| 3   | 20        | 12        |
```